# How to add the username and the password field to drupal bootstrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

Kind of facebook log in.

I dont know how, Im kind a newbie on drupal so please dont tell me bad things

I tried to add a custom block but it dont show the input type.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/trO8t.jpg

Comment: Have you tried just adding the login block to the navigation section?

Comment: Sure but it takes the full width and a height of 300px, also I try to change the css to display it in a right way  but it show "create a new account and the recovery password form and I just want the user field and the password field, again sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You could use form_alter (or form _FORM_ID_alter) to change the default login block. Or you could create your own module that supplies an alternate login block. Then include this block in the navigation section.

Comment: How can I use the form_alter on a hosted drupal? Where can I use that function? System.api.php?

Comment: Search google for how to implement a HOOK_form_alter.

Comment: With css you can hide all links with a {display: none;}

Comment: Sure but the users cant get the "Create a user" link on the log in area.